# Удалить все столбцы матрицы, кроме первых двух

Tags: java, матрицы

Удаляю все столбцы матрицы, кроме первых двух следующим кодом:

```
for (int i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<words[0].length-(words[0].length-2);j++) {
        for (int st=3; st<words[0].length; st++) {
            if(j>=st-1){
                words[i][j]=words[i][j+1];
            } 
        }
        System.out.print(words[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Однако при проверке выясняется, что этот код не удаляет столбцы, а только выводит первые два, поскольку если выводить матрицу отдельным циклом, выводятся опять все элементы. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В чем ошибка?

Попробуем упростить код.

Выражение `words[0].length-(words[0].length-2)` эквивалентно 2 (предполагая, что `words` и `words[0]` не равны `null`). Заменяем:

```
for(int j=0; j<2; j++) {
    for (int st=3; st<words[0].length; st++) {
        if(j>=st-1){
            words[i][j]=words[i][j+1];
        } 
    }
    System.out.print(words[i][j]+" ");
}
```

Условие `j>=st-1` всегда ложно т.к. `st-1 >= 2 > j`. По этой причине внутренний цикл работает вхолостую и ничего не делает. Два верхних цикла выводят массив.

> Удалить все столбцы матрицы, кроме первых двух

Как уже ответил @iksuy массивы нужно пересоздавать для изменения размера. Можно использовать метод [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)):

```
int columnsCount = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = Arrays.copyOf(words[i], columnsCount);
}
```

Если `columnsCount` будет больше текущей длины, то массивы будут дополнены нулями (или `null` в зависимости от типа `words`).

Comment: "Условие j>=st-1 всегда ложно т.к. st-1 >= 2 > j. По этой причине внутренний цикл работает вхолостую и ничего не делает. Два верхних цикла выводят массив." 
с внутренним циклом выводит первые два столбца (0 и 1 индексы соответственно), а без него, выводятся второй и третий (1 и 2 индексы)

Comment: + вопрос вдогонку, что делать с таким "2.37287025676599E-16" выводом вместо нулей?  `System.out.printf("%.2f", words[i][j]+" ");` дает ошибку

Comment: @ВикторияПушкина По приведенному коду так не получается ([прогон на IdeOne](https://ideone.com/e9CAWi)). Попробуйте вообще без внутреннего цикла.

Comment: @ВикторияПушкина `words` какого типа? если double или float, то `+" "` не надо

Comment: последний вопрос) без '+" " ' работает, но выводит не ровно (из-за чисел, которые то с минусом, то без), с этим что-то можно сделать?

Comment: @ВикторияПушкина зависит от того как нужно выравнивать. Можно попробовать задать фиксированную ширину, например: `%6.2f`. Почитайте [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) в ней есть примеры. Если не получится, то это уже тема для нового вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

В обычном массиве удалить столбцы нельзя. Можно только присвоить новое значение внутреннего массива (то есть, строки)

```
@Test
public void te() {
    int newRowLength = 2;
    int[][] words = new int[][]{
            {1,2,3,4},
            {5,6,7,8},
            {9,10,11,12},
            {13,14,15,16}};

    printMatrix(words);

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        int[] newRow = new int[newRowLength];
        for (int j = 0; j < newRowLength; j++){
            newRow[j] = words[i][j];
        }
        words[i] = newRow;
    }

    printMatrix(words);

}

private void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 
> 5 6 7 8 
> 9 10 11 12 
> 13 14 15 16 
>
> 1 2 
> 5 6 
> 9 10 
> 13 14
> ```